# Convert Derived Class to Base Generic Class

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

I have a set up approximately like this:

```
public class A { ... }
public class A<T> : A { ... }
public class B<T> : A<T> { ... }
public class C : B<SomeType> { ... }
```

I am iterating over a list of type A, and I want to check if something is of type B, and if it is, convert it to... B... I can see how it already poses a problem of how am I gonna get the type... but if I cannot do that, what are my other alternatives?

EDIT:
To clarify, B contains a method I'd like to use that A does not contain as it simply has no need for it... I want to check which of the objects on that list are of type B so that I can run this method on them

EDIT 2:
I forgot to mention the A in the middle earlier... sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to check which of the objects on that list are of type B

Then introduce a type B into your type hierarchy. Currently you don't have a type `B`, you've got `B<SomeType>` which is a different type.  so

```
public class A { ... }

public abstract class B : A { ... }

public class B<T> : B { ... }

public class C : B<SomeType> { ... }
```

Or declare the method you want on an interface

```
public class A { ... }
public class A<T> : A { ... }
public interface IB
public class B<T> : A<T>, IB { ... }
public class C : B<SomeType> { ... }
```

Then for any A you can check if it `is IB`.  This is probably the most natural solution since .NET doesn't have multiple inheritance.

Comment: That's... a problem... you see the real tree in my example looks like: A, A<T>, B<T>, C... I cannot introduce a B in the middle

Comment: You can, you'd have to change your code, but `B<T>` is a different type than `B`. The other option is to use reflection. Call `GetType` on `this` and then query whether it's a generic type, and what whether it's a `B<T>` and what type `T` is

Comment: That I can do, I've already found a stack overflow question talking about how to CHECK if it is of a certain generic type... but I do not know how to properly convert... I tried Convert.ChangeType but it wasn't successful

Comment: The interface might be a good, altho weird looking solution... but seems like my best hope so I will do that, thank you!

Comment: You don't need to _convert_ it to the `B<T>` type; it already is an object of that type. What you can't do is assigned it to a variable of that type without an explicit cast